# Launch the specified app and force it back to the home screen

Tags: screen

I'm currently trying to go back to the home screen as shown below, but this will only bring me back to this app (the app I'm working on). For example, I can't go back to YouTube.

```
// ホーム画面に戻るためのIntentを作成
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//ホーム画面に戻る
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Nothing happens.Could it be related to the backstack or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour[ and read up on [ask]. In particular, the sole tag [tag:screen] tells us, well, nothing. What language did you use? Which API? Are you programming for a certain OS? [Edit] the post to contain more relevant tags and information in order for us to be able to help you.